# conditionalPanel to link sidebars and make appropriate selections - Shiny R

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have an UI designed as shown in the picture below, and I want to actually set a condition here such that:

[UI.R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fdug.png)

On selecting/checking the box "Saddle Joint" from the sidebar `location`, I want the options "GEO_10500", "GEO_77298" to be chosen from the sidebar `Datasets:`. Here's the server code I tried and it didn't work. Let me know how this could be achieved. Thanks!

Server.R

`conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.location = 'Saddle Joint'",
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                           "datasets", 
                           "Datasets:",
                           choices=c("GEO_10500", "GEO_77298"), 
                           selected = "GEO_10500"
  )
)`

Server.R

`

```
observe({

if ("input.location== 'Saddle Joint'") {

  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                           "datasets", "Datasets:", choices = c("GEO_15602","GEO_21537"),
                           selected= c("GEO_15602","GEO_21537"))
}

})
```

`

Comment: @ Dean Attali : Could you help me with this?

Comment: `conditionalPanel` is to be used on the ui side and you cannot combine it with `updateCheckboxGroupInput` which is to be used on the server side. You should instead use `observeEvent` and `update...` on the server side.

Comment: @warmoverflow : ` observeEvent(input$location=="Saddle Joint", {
    
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "datasets", "Datasets:", choices = "x",
                             selected= "x")
    
    
  })` I tried this on the server side and the datasets get checked on before I even make a selection from the location panel?